# Creating table from txt with delimiter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, txt

At the moment I'm trying to automate the process of creating excel files from SAP tables. We always import a total of 50 different tables from the SAP system in the form of a txt file with the delimiter '|'. Unfortunately in some tables this delimiters appears also in the column itself and thus when using pandas I get an error message. Additionally I tried to use the pandas `read_fwf`, but this was not working either. Any idea on how to solve this? An example of such table is given below:

| Number | Date | Time | Request | Clt | Owner | User | Project | Short Text | RC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06.01.21 | 12:01:56 | OD1K984128 | 300 | FX5314 | F36164 |  | 8000013814 : P|303 CAS change interface PR SAP |  |
| 2 | 06.01.21 | 12:01:58 | OD1K984193 | 300 | FX5314 | F36164 |  | 8000013814 : P|303 CAS change interface PR SAP (2) |  |
| 3 | 07.01.21 | 12:07:49 | OD1K984028 | 300 | FX5310 | F36164 |  | 8000013709, INC0242318 change pop-up label printing |  |
| 4 | 07.01.21 | 12:07:50 | OD1K984179 | 300 | FX5370 | F36164 |  | 8000013834 - MRP areas in the US - Adapt ZBW_KNMT |  |
| 5 | 07.01.21 | 12:07:52 | OD1K984202 | 300 | F38091 | F36164 |  | 8000013839, INC0208178 Adapt spare part availability |  |
| 6 | 07.01.21 | 12:07:52 | OD1K984288 | 300 | F36131 | F36164 |  | 8000013862 : CCK Z004 for 7502 |  |
| 7 | 07.01.21 | 12:07:55 | OD1K984036 | 300 | F36131 | F36164 |  | 8000013797: storloc CN70 |  |
| 8 | 07.01.21 | 12:08:17 | OD1K984345 | 300 | FX5248 | F36164 |  | 8000013880, Johannfreight auth - INC0261847 |  |
| 9 | 07.01.21 | 12:08:18 | OD1K984347 | 300 | VASA10053690 | F36164 |  | 8000013883 2109-US6A |  |
| 10 | 07.01.21 | 12:08:18 | OD1K984005 | 300 | VASA10053690 | F36164 |  | 8000013884 Production Sched Profile 7502/75A2 |  |
| 11 | 07.01.21 | 12:08:22 | OD1K984360 | 300 | FX5248 | F36164 |  | 8000013886, Auth C088 - 3101 - F|10010 - INC0262223 |  |
| 12 | 07.01.21 | 12:08:49 | OD1K984374 | 300 | FX5248 | F36164 |  | 8000013889, CK13N - F39115 - INC0262507 |  |
| 13 | 07.01.21 | 12:08:50 | OD1K984351 | 300 | VASA10053690 | F36164 |  | 8000013884 Production Sched |Profile|7502/75A2 |  |
| 14 | 07.01.21 | 12:08:51 | OD1K984356 | 300 | FX5314 | F36164 |  | 8000013885 : P00303 Customs Declaration C4T (4) |  |
| 15 | 07.01.21 | 12:08:52 | OD1K984358 | 300 | FX5295 | F36164 |  | 8000013885, P00303 Customs Declaration C4T (4) |  |
| 16 | 07.01.21 | 12:08:52 | OD1K984381 | 300 | VASA10053690 | F36164 |  | 8000013893 ZAP |  |

I'm trying to convert the data to a dataframe is not working properly if there is a delimiter ('|') within the column itself I get an error that it expected x columns but saw y columns. I know the reason of the error (since there is a delimiter inside the column) but I don't know how to tackle it.

```
def exporting_xlsx(file_name, xlsx_path):
#creating the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(file_name,
        delimiter = '|',
        index_col= False,
        header=0,
        squeeze = True,
        skipinitialspace = True,
        low_memory = False,
        skip_blank_lines = True,
        on_bad_lines='warn',
        na_filter = True,
        dtype=str)

#dropping empty columns
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]

#exporting the file to xlsx
df.to_excel(xlsx_path, index = None, header=True)
```

Executing this code on the table, results in the following error message and as a result thus not exporting each line. Additionally some part of column 1 and 2 are put in the column RC due the '|' in the column.

```
b'Skipping line 14: expected 13 fields, saw 14\n'
```

Does somebody has any idea how to tackle this issue? Thank you in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a Python library called tabulate. Try it out.

https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/

You can convert the table to a Pandas Dataframe and then you can feed the dataframe into `tabulate.tabulate()`.

Comment: That did not really solve my problem. Could you maybe give some more details on how I should handle it?